# I would like to return a value without duplicates in order

Tags: python, set

This is my code:

```
value = input("
What would you like to return without duplicate values?\n")

set_value = set(value)
list_value = list(set_value)
sorted_value = sorted(list_value)
print(value)
```

My mistake is that I cannot get the duplicates back after converting to a list.

To let you know why the code is bad, I literally started last week and therefore don't know how to apply many of the techniques.

It would be helpful if someone could write the answer in full.

Example: 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, f, k, f
Result: 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, f, k, f
Expected Result: 1, 5, f, k

(PS. This is in python3 at Repl.it).

Comment: Try to solve the problem on paper. List out the steps you would take if you didn't have a set object to remove your duplicates for you. What type of control structures would you use? Maybe a  for loop to loop through your initial list? Maybe store off in a dict to count duplicates? Give it a go. Being a good programmer is about solving problems and less writing code.

Comment: At the end of the code you're printing `value`, which is the original input.  Presumably you meant to print `sorted_value` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing `value` instead of `sorted_value`.
However `sorted_value` is:

```
[' ', ',', '1', '5', 'f', 'k']
```

If you want it to be:

```
['1', '5', 'f', 'k']
```

You would need to change your code to:

```
value = input("What would you like to return without duplicate values?\n")
value = value.split(", ")
set_value = set(value)
list_value = list(set_value)
sorted_value = sorted(list_value)
print(sorted_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save each time if you are not going to use intermediate results. You can change your code as below

```
print(sorted(list(set_value))) #['1', '5', 'f', 'k']
```

```
value = ["1", "1", "1", "5", "5", "f", "k", "f"]
set_value = set(value) #{'1', '5', 'k', 'f'}
list_value = list(set_value) #['k', '5', 'f', '1']
sorted_value = sorted(list_value) #['1', '5', 'f', 'k']
print(sorted_value)
```

You have to print the `sorted_value` instead of the value